# How to make POST API URL

Tags: api, url, post

I have question about POST API.

I've made simple website. On the other side I have program which is sending some json data with POST method. Person who made this api want me to give them URL for this. I've never deal with api's so it's very difficult for me to find some starting point. Any one can help with some tutorial or advice? ;)

Comment: Well you should be clearer on what kind of API are you working on to get a focussed answer

Comment: What you're asking is very broad, and you may be confusing some of your terminology here.  If you need to expose a service of some kind then you have the learning curve of building your web application.  What the URL is will be the easy part, once you've created your HTTP API interface.  If *someone else* has built an API that you are using, then *they* should be giving *you* the URL of that API.  It's really not clear what specifically you mean.

Comment: Thanks for answer.
I have problem with call it correctly. 
Person who made api said: "Give me an URL, where I can send JSON statement using POST method. So as far as I understand they want to send JSON package directly to my website ?

Comment: @Huraganek: Then that person is asking *you* to create an API that *their* application will integrate with.  Whatever server-side language you're using (PHP? JavaScript/Node.js? C#? Python? Something else?  If nothing then you'll need to pick one and get started) you would need to find some tutorials on how to make an API in that language/framework/etc.

Comment: I am using PHP.